# How can I JOIN tables conditionally?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am working with a badly designed database and I ran into some problem.

I have two tables that I need to join on a 'not unique ID'.
The software that currently works with the database sets a '0 value' in the id if there is an error. This means if I try to join them a massive amount of records is joined on the 0 values.

Underneath an example of two tables and their not unique id fields i want to join them on

```
tbl1    tbl2
-----------       
2        2
3        6
4        5
0        3
0        4
6        0
5        0
----------
```

What I want to achieve is this

```
tbl1    tbl2
-----------         
2        2
3        3
4        4
0        * (no join)
0        * (no join)
6        6
5        5
----------
```

In other words, I don't want the '0 values' from tbl1 to join with all other '0 values' from tbl2. I still want to have the record tbl1 without a join though.

Is this possible in 1 query?

extra information: SQL SERVER 2005 and there is no option to make the ID's unique.

Comment: So do you want values in rows 4 and 5 or not? If you don't want the rows to be present where tbl1.id = 0, then don't include them in your desired results please. I was fooled into believing you wanted rows there but you wanted null values instead of showing 0s from table2.

Comment: At first sight your NULLIF solution worked as well for me (perhaps a slightly cleaner solution). I do want the rows to be present where tbl1.id = 0 I just don't want the fields from tbl2 joined with those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.value = tbl2.value and tbl2.value <> 0
```

this will give null values on the two that you put as *

Answer (score 3):

You did not show us the full structure of the tables so I need to make up some columns, but it basically goes like this:

```
select *
from tbl1
   join tbl2 
     on tbl1.id = tbl2.t1_id 
    and tbl1.that_flag <> 0
```

Note the `and` condition that is part of the `join` condition.

Comment: sir question, wht is the difference between your query and adding the `tbl2.that_flag = 0` on where clause? :)

Comment: @JohnWoo: no technical difference for an inner join. But I personally think it makes the intention clearer and it **will** make a difference if an outer join is used.

Comment: Your query did gave me inspiration, I used this : `select *
from tbl1
   join tbl2 
     on tbl1.id = tbl2.t1_id 
    and tbl2.id <> 0
`

Comment: @AaronBertrand: true. I should be `<> 0`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl2.id
FROM dbo.tbl1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl2
ON tbl1.id = NULLIF(tbl2.id, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this solution has a huge impact on my performance. If someone knows why feel free to explain. The full query (I did not include in the original post for explaining purposes) uses paging like this: `WHERE limit BETWEEN 1771 AND 1800` . This took me 50 seconds to complete. a `WHERE limit BETWEEN 1 AND 30` took me 1 second. The `and tbl2.value <> 0` solution from the accepted answer above took me less than a second in both paging scenarios.

Comment: @BBQ hard to say without knowing the query, table structure, indexes, cardinality, etc. My version could be leading to a scan but without being able to generate meaningful execution plans it's really difficult for outsiders to pinpoint precise reasons for execution time differences. On a simple schema my query produced the exact same execution plan as the accepted answer. On your schema, with your query, there may be some difference I simply can't account for.

Comment: Researching this on another system is quite impossible indeed. I guess I was hoping for a simple explanation :). Just fyi this is the query I use `SELECT * FROM(SELECT *,  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Colmun1 DESC) AS limit  
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON Colmun1 = Colmun2 and Column2 <> 0) orderedList 
WHERE limit BETWEEN 1771 AND 1800` and both tables have over 6000 records with at least 8 fields per table.

Comment: 6000 rows and it is taking 50 seconds? That can't possibly be my query's fault. Unfortunately it is impossible for me to troubleshoot without a lot more information.